# Setting the hostname in the linux shell prompt

Tags: linux, centos

I have an ec2 instance. When I log in, it will prompt this:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-128-80-10 ~]$
```

I want to rewrite the ip-10-128-80-10 to some nickname, such as us1, us2, us3.

```
[ec2-user@us1 ~]$
```

How to set it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's the system's hostname, which you can set in `/etc/hostname`.

Next, execute this as root

```
$ service hostname restart
```

Comment: if by chance you want to go beyond just setting the host name, your shell has variables to set it's prompt string template (with the hostname and other things wherever you like, or without them).

Comment: It works after rebooting :)

Comment: You didn't have to reboot, but rather could have likely just run `$ service hostname restart`.

Comment: Probably only needed a logout/logbackin, or maybe even just "exec ${SHELL} -i".

Answer (score 4):

Note that you don't have to change the hostname if you prefer not to.  If you just want to change the prompt, you can set the shell variable PS1.  At the moment, it's probably set to something like this:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \w]\$ '
```

You can set it to anything you like, e.g.

```
PS1='\u@test1234 \w\$ '
```